# php get object from url

Tags: javascript, php

I have a url like below, which I got after doing `jQuery.param( jObj );` on my js obj,
Now I want to get the article_id from this url in my php script.

```
www.url.com/article?data%5Barticle_id%5D=42
```

In other form the url is `www.url.com/article?data[article_id]=42`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at `$_GET['data']['article_id']`.  PHP will automatically make these associative arrays, if there are brackets in the variable name.

Comment: can't accept an answer until 10mins from posting the question.